# Tailwind button not visible

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

In this Laravel code the two  links that are Tailwind-styled as buttons are visible, however, the button is not. It is there and clickable, but not visible. Any suggestions?

```
<form action="{{ route('suppliers.destroy', $supplier->id) }}" method="post">
  @csrf
  @method('DELETE')
  <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this product?');" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest">
    Delete
  </button>
  <a href="{{ route('suppliers.show', $supplier) }}" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest">
    View
  </a>
  <a href="{{ route('suppliers.edit', $supplier) }}" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest">
    Edit
  </a>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm able to view the buttons when I add that code to my site. I'd suggest examining it in your browser's developer tools, and see if there's a parent overriding the visibility

Comment: Thanks, I was loading the css of mckenziearts/laravel-notify after tailwind css.  I changed the order and now it is working.